# Querying a 1 to many table where the many side has at least one row

Tags: mysql, sql

Have a common schema, with two tables.

`users` table contains the columns `id`, `name`.
`checkins` table contains the columns `user_id`, `checkin_date`.

in this hypothetical, `users` can have many instances of rows in the `checkins` table.

`checkin_date` in this case is of type `date`

I want to be able to query for all users who have at minimum 1 checkin in the checkins table where the checkin is after 2016.

Comment: Just do a simple `INNER JOIN` matching the pk/fk and that date is greater than or equal '2016/01/01'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `exists`:

```
select u.*
from users u
where exists (select 1
              from checks c
              where c.user_id = u.id and c.checkin_date >= '2016-01-01'
             );
```